# NestJS on Heroku always failing to bind port

Tags: heroku, nestjs

I am trying to deploy my NestJS REST API on Heroku but I always get the following error:

```
 Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

My configuration is pretty straight forward:

1. In my `main.ts` I start my server with:

   `await app.listen(process.env.PORT || AppModule.port);`
2. I added a Procfile in the root directory of my project which contains:

   `web: npm run start:prod`
3. My package.json files contains these scripts:

   `"build": "tsc -p tsconfig.build.json",
    "prestart:prod": "rimraf dist && npm run build",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main.js",`

The process on Heroku builds succesfully, prints out these seamingly reassuring lines:

```
TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized
SharedModule dependencies initialized
AppModule dependencies initialized
```

But then immediately crashes with:

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

I use .env configuration across my application but I removed all HOST and PORT variables (and code references), so I have no clue what could be the cause of this error.
Am I missing something?

> EDIT
>   I am hereby sharing my app.module and main.ts files:

app.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [SharedModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres',
        host: configService.getString('POSTGRES_HOST'),
        port: configService.getNumber('POSTGRES_DB_PORT'),
        username: configService.getString('POSTGRES_USER'),
        password: configService.getString('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        database: configService.getString('POSTGRES_DB'),
        entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      } as PostgresConnectionOptions),
    }),
    UserModule,
  ],
  controllers: [
    AppController,
  ],
  providers: [
    AppService,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
  static port: number;
  static isDev: boolean;

  constructor(configurationService: ConfigService) {
    console.log(process.env.PORT);
    AppModule.port = configurationService.getNumber('PORT');
    AppModule.isDev = configurationService.getBoolean('ISDEV');
  }
}
```

My configuration.service.ts is a simple utility that reads from .env files:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as path from 'path';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  constructor() {
      const filePath = path.resolve('.env');
      dotenv.config({
      path: filePath,
    });
  }

  getNumber(key: string): number | undefined {
    return +process.env[key] as number | undefined;
  }

  getBoolean(key: string): boolean {
    return process.env[key] === 'true';
  }

  getString(key: string): string | undefined {
    return process.env[key];
  }
}
```

And finally my main.ts file:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  console.log(process.env.PORT);
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe(), new TimeStampPipe());
  app.use(json({ limit: '5mb' }));

  app.setGlobalPrefix('api/v1');
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || AppModule.port);
}
bootstrap();
```

Could it be that my `configuration.service.ts` is interfering with heroku's env file?

Comment: Hey, did you print a console.log of the process.env.PORT to see the value ?

Comment: Awesome idea!! Let me try

Comment: @AdrienDePeretti if I put my console log in the main.ts bootstrap function the execution never reaches there. However if I add a constructor to the AppModule class I see it's using port 29224... After that the process crashes (before reaching main.ts)

Comment: Could you share a bit of code please

Comment: @AdrienDePeretti done :) Thank you so much for looking into this!

Comment: Don’t forget to add your configServices into the providers collection :) that’s a first thing or is it in the shareModule ?

Comment: If the main.js is well called the first log we should see is the one in the main when the bootstrap is called as far i can see

Comment: @AdrienDePeretti turns out the issue was on the db server that was not accepting connection from heroku... sorry for wasting your time...however I think the error message is quite deceiving!

Comment: And a small tip, you should’t have to set your port and and isDev like this you can access the config service after you have created the app using app.get(configService)

Comment: @AdrienDePeretti thanks, good tip!

Comment: If i well understand the connection to your db created the timeout ?

Comment: Yeah exactly...

Comment: Wired ... is the link for the applicationContext https://docs.nestjs.com/application-context

Comment: @AdrienDePeretti yeah really weird..especially because the log said that the TypeORM module was initializes

Comment: What was the resolution for the next time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a summary, be careful on the database connection timeout that could lead to a global timeout of the heroku bootstrap as describe above

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **fastify** instead express as your platform, you need to define the **host** to `0.0.0.0` explicitly like this :

```
const port = process.env.PORT || AppModule.port;
const host = '0.0.0.0';
await app.listen(port, host);
```

This problem is caused by the fastify library. See the related discussion here: [Fastify with Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66743455/fastify-with-heroku).