# Fastify with Heroku

Tags: heroku, fastify

I am having a simple Fastify server hosted with Heroku. But, it seems not working ! But, it seemed all right during the development! The error I get is: `Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`. Full error I am getting:

[image]

Here is the code I am using: 
`server.js`:

```
const fastify = require("fastify")();
const path = require("path");

fastify.register(require("fastify-static"), {
  root: path.join(__dirname, "/"),
});

fastify.get("/", function (req, reply) {
  reply.sendFile("index.html");
});

fastify.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(`server listening on ${fastify.server.address().port}`);
});
```

`package.json`:

```
{
"name": "test1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "15.11.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "fastify": "^3.14.0",
    "fastify-static": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

Sometimes, the site even doesn't load! 
Any help is greatly appreciated ! 
Thanks !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's an issue with the library. For other libraries (express, django, etc..) specifying the address is not necessary.

See https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/709

Change:

```
.listen(process.env.PORT)
```

to:

```
.listen(process.env.PORT, '0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: I had to change it to the new syntax so `.listen({port: process.env.PORT || 3000, host: '0.0.0.0'})`

Answer (score 2):

When I use both nodemon as local server and Heroku for production the following works for me:

```
await fastify.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0');
```

and in package.json

```
"dev": "PORT=${PORT:=3000} HOST=${HOST:=localhost} nodemon"
```